# Convert text to timestamp in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, to-date, to-timestamp

I have a text field "presence_changed_at" with text values i.e. `'2014/12/17 08:05:28 +0000`. I need to convert this into timestamp. In postgreSQL there is function *TO_TIMESTAMP()*, however in **redshift** this does not seem to be supported. I can get the date without time by

```
TO_DATE("presence_changed_at",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

which produces

```
2014-12-12
```

but i can't find any way to get TIMESTAMP format.

Thanks in advance for solving this

Comment: Did you try COVERT ... as timestamp? Please note that it is better to do the conversion as part of the COPY command over as part of the queries.

Answer (score 11):

```
cast(column as timestamp)
```

worked for me on redshift. See http://devdocs.io/postgresql~9.4/sql-expressions#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Answer (score 4):

try convert function:

```
convert(timestamp,presence_changed_at)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `CONVERT()`; however, this function only works when the string is in the very format implicit to the host (the default string format).  I'd like to find something similar to `TO_TIMESTAMP()` so that I can pass it an arbitrary date format.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast it to a timestamp. This supports quite a few reasonable formats without having to specify one.

```
select '2014/12/17 08:05:28 +0000'::timestamp;

      timestamp
---------------------
 2014-12-17 08:05:28

select '2014-12-02T05:00:00'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2014-12-02 05:00:00

select '2014-12-02T05:00:00PM'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2014-12-02 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

It's surprisingly horrible to get a datetime from a unixtime in redshift without a subselect.  However, you can do this:

`select timestamptz 'epoch' + YOURTIME * interval '1 second'`

Comment: You can also do TIMESTAMP if your times are all stored in UTC and you don't use TIMESTAMPTZ columns

Answer (score 3):

Below functions worked for me correctly... Use whichever is applicable for you...

cast(column_name as timestamp)

to_date(column_name,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

to_date(column_name,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS')

to_timestamp(column_name,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Answer (score 2):

Please use `TO_Timestamp("presence_changed_at",'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` to get the desired output

Comment: Helpful, but it appends a +00 since it's a TIMESTAMPTZ data type - what if my data is not in UTC?  That +00 is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP(presence_changed_at,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` which will return a `TIMESTAMPTZ` value, which can be cast to `TIMESTAMP` using `::TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: How to convert a timestamp string from one time zone to another.
e.g. "YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS UTC"  to a EST timezone.

Comment: @ManojKumar use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html

Answer (score 1):

As of today, to_timestamp is supported by redshift. So, your SQL query should work. Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on a database where a date & time variable was stored as text in a VARCHAR type, *in multiple different formats* (don't ask...), and had to convert it to a TIMESTAMP type.
Since there is no `TO_TIMESTAMP()` function in Redshift, I used the trick suggested by Yiyu Jia on his [blog][1].  In a nutshell, the trick is to

- use TO_DATE() to get the date converted
- append the time portion of the input text to the above
- CAST the resulting string to a TIMESTAMP

For example here's the snippet to deal with a field named myDate with dates in either of the following formats

- "Feb  8 2013 10:06PM"
- "25/09/2007 16:21:00"

It is rather heavy, but works. A regex test is used to test if the date corresponds to the format handled on a given line. (that is only necessary when dealing with multiple possible formats)
  The 'Feb 0 2013' case is a bit more complicated because I remove the time portion of the text, before submitting it to TO_DATE(), and because another regex is used to extract the time portion that is appended (as opposed the simpler SUBSTRING() used for the same purpose, in the other case).

```
... ,
CASE
  -- Special date indicating "date not available": replaced by NULL
  WHEN myDate = '31/12/9999 23:59:59' OR myDate = 'Dec 31 9999 11:59PM' THEN NULL 
  -- 'Feb  8 2013 10:06PM' case
  WHEN myDate ~ '^[JFMASOND][a-z]{2}'  THEN
      CAST(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(myDate , '\\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}[AP]M$', ''), 'Mon FMDD YYYY') || REGEXP_REPLACE(myDate , '[JFMASOND][a-z]{2}\\s+[0-9]{1,2}\\s+[0-9]{4}\\s+', ' ') AS TIMESTAMP)
  -- '25/09/2007 16:21:00' case
  WHEN myDate ~ '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} '  THEN
      CAST(TO_DATE(myDate , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || SUBSTRING(myDate FROM 11) AS TIMESTAMP)
  ELSE NULL
END AS MyNiceTimeStamp, 
...

  [1]: http://yiyujia.blogspot.com/2014/04/redshift-convert-integer-to-timestamp.html
```

Comment: putting a case in has severe performance implications.  the regexp has severe performance and correctness implications.

Answer (score 0):

If **datecolumn** format is "**2021-01-13T12:14:43Z**" (varchar)

For converting to ***timestamptz*** datatype:

```
to_timestamp(datecolumn, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
```

For converting to ***timestamp*** datatype:

```
cast(datecolumn as timestamp)
```

Both will result in same output format "**2021-01-13 12:14:43.000000**"

Comment: how to convert a time only string to time.
e.g. '17:30:43' is a time without date. I want to convert it to time datatype.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-time

Comment: I am assuming you also have a date string since the time string alone wouldn't make sense ? In that case you can always combine these strings and then perform the conversion to timestamp. Post this you can further split the date & time using something like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html

Comment: No, I only have the time. There is no date.

Comment: in that case you can just create a placeholder date string like '2023-01-31' and combine it with your time string and then go from there.