# Convert text column to timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Currently, I have .csv data uploaded to my Redshift cluster in the following format (sample):

```
period_start            glance_view_count
2016/01/01 03:00 PST    0
2016/01/01 04:00 PST    800
2016/01/01 05:00 PST    100
2016/02/09 12:00 PST    99
2016/02/09 13:00 PST    18
```

`period_start` is currently `text` data type.

I would like to insert this data into a separate table where the `period_start` column is formatted `timestamp` or `timestamptz`. Is there a `TO_DATE()` function or similar I can call to convert `text` to the desired format?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for this! `to_timestamp(period_start, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI') as period_start` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert text to timestamp in redshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636304/convert-text-to-timestamp-in-redshift)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to another user, per this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html

`SELECT to_timestamp(ios.period_start, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI') as period_start` does the trick!